# How to show profile picture on the webpage in symfony 2 using path stored on the database

Tags: php, symfony

How can I show the profile picture on the webpage using the path stored on the database in symfony 2?

I have a code in my entity like this:

```
public function setProfilePath($profilePath)
{
    $this->profilePath = $profilePath;

    return $this;
}

/**
* Get profilePath
*
* @return string
*/
public function getProfilePath()
{
    return $this->profilePath;
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}


public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->path
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->path
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded
    // documents should be saved
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

protected function getUploadDir()
{
    // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
    // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
    return 'uploads/documents';
}

/**
 * 
 */
private $file;

/**
 * Sets file.
 *
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 */
public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;
}

/**
 * Get file.
 *
 * @return UploadedFile
 */
public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}
```

and a code like this in my controller:

```
public function showImageAction($id)
{
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('MatrixUserBundle:User')
        ->find($id);

    if (!is_object($user)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }



    return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Profile:show_content.html.twig', array('user' => $user));

}
```

And in my twig file I have the difficulty in showing the profile picture for a user in which the image path is stored in the database and the image itself is stored in the file system.

How can I do it using symfony 2 assets?

Comment: where is the image stored in the file system?

Comment: @Chausser it is stored in this folder .../web/profilePictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, save your image in web/bundles/profile/pictures for example for a better structure.

In twig, you need to use '~' for concatenating a variable.

Your code would look like:

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/profile/pictures/' ~ variable) }}">
```

which in your case would be:

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/profile/pictures/' ~ user.profilePath) }}">
```

That would work if you're saving only the name of the image.
In case you're saving the whole path, you will need to replace 'bundles/profile/pictures' with the appropriate prefix, keeping in mind that asset() starts at /web/

Comment: I have encountered an exception during the showing of the image and it says that An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined property: Matrix\MatrixUserBundle\Entity\User::$getProfilePath in C:\xampp\htdocs\editracker\vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\Model\User.php line 833") in FOSUserBundle:Profile:show_content.html.twig at line 279.

How can I fix it when I have already put the :$getProfilePath in the user-bundle\Model\User.php